# loading large Datasets from DB. Entity Framework DB first

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity framework generated CodeModel. (Database first). 
All of these are views in the database. 
        public class TypeCode 
        {
        public string Code;
        public string Description
        }
      public class TypeCode1 
        {
        public string Code;
        public string Description
        }

Each time the application opens we are loading these codes from Views. This takes quite of bit of time(3mins) just for some initializing data to load.(each time the application opens). I have like 1000 of these TypeCode types- TypeCode1, TypeCode2..All the TypeCodes have the same structure Code, Description

This is how we are loading the codeslist

```
using(SQlEntitiesContext _context = new SQlEntitiesContext())
{
TypeCodes = _context.TypeCode.ToList();
 TypeCodes1 = _context.TypeCode1.ToList();.....
..
..
..
}
```

I would like to build a webservice which could load all these lists(they do not change) and use them when needed for each instance of the application. Preferably not query the DB for each instance of the application.  Webservice will do more stuff not just the Codes.It will load and cache all the codes to start with. 
Currently it takes longer because of the network

So I started the wcfService like this

```
  public interface ICodesService
    {
        [OperationContract]
            Codes LoadCodeData();
    }
     [Serializable]
        [DataContract]
        public class Codes
        {
            [DataMember]
            public List<TypeCode> TypeCodes{ get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public List<TypeCode1> TypeCodes1{ get; set; }
    }
    }

LoadCodes.svc


    public class LoadCodesService : ICodesService
        {
            Codes _AllCodes = new Codes();
       public Codes LoadCodeData()
            {

                using (CodeEntities _codes = new CodeEntities())
                {

                    _AllCodes.TypeCodes= _codes.TypeCode.ToList();
                    _AllCodes.TypeCodes1= _codes.TypeCodes.ToList();
             }
         }
```

On the Client

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadCodesServiceReference.CodesServiceClient proxy = new LoadCodesServiceReference.CodesServiceClient();
            _codes = proxy.LoadCodeData();


        }
```

I would like to know if making any of these objects static would be a good idea. For each instance of the application being loaded. Can we somehow cache the existing codes and reuse when needed. What are some options available? Using DataReader is not an option.

Comment: This sounds like you want to use caching in WCF, which isn't Entity Framework related. You may be able to find your answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider a static factory method that on the first time your types are created queries their state from the db, but thereafter caches them and returns an object hydrated with your cache rather than a call to the Db. You can put your caching logic there as well then behind the factory method, and any improvements over time will go to all objects created.

Something like this:

```
public static class SingletonData
{
    static private List<TypeCode> _TypeCode;

    public static List<TypeCode> TypeCode
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_TypeCode!=null)  return _TypeCode;
            using (var db = new SQlEntitiesContainer())
            {
                _TypeCode = db.TypeCodes.ToList();
                return _TypeCode;
            }
        }           
    }

    static private List<TypeCode1> _TypeCode1;

    public static List<TypeCode1> TypeCode1
    {
        get
        {
            if (_TypeCode1 != null) return _TypeCode1;
            using (var db = new SQlEntitiesContainer())
            {
                _TypeCode1 = db.TypeCode1.ToList();
                return _TypeCode1;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would like to try this out. Do you have any example? just to see what I should be looking at

Comment: I edited my response above. You don't have to make the class static, but I think the List<TypeCode> should be static so there is only one copy in memory no matter how many of the class are created. You could expand it to check and see if new items were added to the db since the singleton had been created, but I don't really see that as part of your use case, so I didn't add it. Hope it helps.